# 'software-properties-common' not found in package names. Trying capabilities

Tags: linux, bash, opensuse

I am trying to install latte dock on an openSUSE KDE linux machine, but my add-apt-repository command does not work. What's more, when i try to install software-properties-common, it says that there is no provider for that package:

```
> sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'software-properties-common' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'software-properties-common' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

I tried zypper up and zypper patch I looked on couple of websites but no answer yet. As I saw this was kind of a 'commune' issue, but still no answer that worked yet.

Answer (score 1):

**I strongly feel this with help you.**

Faced similar issue in my case I have deleted content of /etc/apt/source.list/ hence I was not able to update my repositories. I set this file to its default content.

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

After which I was able to install the above package successfully.

Note - Replace **bionic** with your appropriate version

Approach 2:
If above method fails try this as well.
Download deb file for above [software-common-properties](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/software-properties-common/download)
Install the debian package

```
dpkg -i /path/software-common-properties.deb
```